# PostgreSQL. Ввод номера телефона

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как ограничить поля воода номера телефона, чтобы пользователь не вводил всекие там "11256366", а нормально начиная с кода страны ?

Comment: У Вас пользователь в БД сразу вводит?

Comment: @XelaNimed Да, сразу идет запись в БД

Comment: Поле ввода где находится? Ну и как-бы `1` это код США и Канады. Если у Вас `сразу идет запись в БД`, то лучше создать отдельный столбец для кода страны.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это поможет в Вашем вопросе [Google's common Java, C++ and JavaScript library for parsing, formatting, and validating international phone numbers.](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

А вот здесь [libphonenumber](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164796/how-do-i-store-phone-numbers-in-postgresql) с примером PgSQL